# How to list files in a directory, sorted by size, but without listing folder sizes?

Tags: linux, bash, du

I'm writing a bash script that should output the first 10 heaviest files in a directory and all subfolders (the directory is passed to the script as an argument).
And for this I use the following command:
[`sudo du -haS ../../src/ | sort -hr`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPaOK.png)
, but its output contains folder sizes, and I only need files. Help!

Comment: Does `ls -lS DIRECTORY | awk '{print $9}' | head -10` help you?

Comment: @BenYoo: Wouldn't this fail if there is a file with a space in the name?

Comment: @user1934428 I guess quotes will be required if there's space in the name.  
`ls -lS 'DIR NAME' | awk '{print $9}' | head -10`

Comment: @BenYoo : Quotes don't help here: The output of  `ls` just lists the file names, and `$9` will be the first part of the file name, up to the space. You would have to output all fields from $9 to the end.

Comment: @user1934428 That's right, thank you. I misread your comment and thought you were talking about space in directory name. Perhaps this works:  
`ls -lS DIRECTORY | awk '{for(i=9;i<=NF;++i){printf "%s ", $i}; printf "\n"}'`

Comment: This would skip hidden entries (thos starting with a period), and it would also output the name of subdirectories. They are contained in the output of `ls` with size 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
dir="../../src/"
sudo find "$dir" -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 10 | cut -f2-
```

- `find "$dir" -type f` searches `$dir` for files recursively.
- The `-printf "%s\t%p\n"` option tells `find` to print the filesize
  and the filename delimited by a tab character.
- The final `cut -f2-` in the pipeline prints the 2nd and the following
  columns, dropping the filesize column only.

It will work with the filenames which contain special characters such as a whitespace except for
a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Why using `du` at all? You could do a

```
ls -S1AF
```

This will list all entries in the current directoriy, sorted descending by size. It will also include the names of the subdirectories, but they will be at the end (because the size of a directory entry is always zero), and you can recognize them because they have a slash at the end.

To exclude those directories and pick the first 10 lines, you can do a

```
ls -S1AF | head -n 10 | grep -v '/$'
```

**UPDATE**:

If your directory contains not only subdirectories, but also files of length zero, some of those empty files might not be shown in the output, as pointed out in the comment by F.Hauri. If this is an issue for your application, I suggest to exchange the order and do a

```
ls -S1AF | grep -v '/$' | head -n 10
```

instead.

Comment: `ls` lists only the files in the given directory. And I need to know all the nested files, in all the folders that are inside :(

Comment: You did not write this in the question. Please amend your question to express exactly what you want to achieve. Aside from this, you can always use `find` to traverse the directory tree and apply my solution to each folder.

Comment: You wrote *exclude those directories and pick the first 10 lines* but your code do this on reverse sens: You have to switch `grep` and `head` order if you want 10 lines! `ls -S1AF | grep -v '/$' | head -n 10` !!

Comment: @F.Hauri : The sorting happens first by virtue of the `-S` flag. The directories will be last (because they have size 0). The output of the `head` is a couple of files (sorte by size), possibly followed by a few directories (if there are less than 10 files, but subdirectories). The `grep` gets rid of the directories. Perhaps it should be noted that my approach fails if we have file- and/or directory names which contain a newline character. This problem is also present in the code by the OP.

Comment: @F.Hauri : It is not wrong to switch _grep_ and _head_. Actually, if we also have plain files of size zero in addition to subdirectories, they might get lost in my case. I will update my answer accordingly. I don't know whether the OP has interest in getting an accurate record of zero-length files.

Comment: @user1934428 sorry, my english is not very good, i translate via google and so i missed this detail. i need also the sizes of the files from the folders inside the directory) But thank you for your help) I was able to solve my problem with the find command

Comment: @AndreyRomashev: I would separate the parts: First generate a list of the files you are interested in, and then loop over the files and then calculate the file size (using `wc` or `stat`). I think this is cleaner and easier for maintenance (for instance, if you get the idea one day that you want to do yet different things with the files, or reduce the output only to files which are larger a certain limit).